# JBoss Fuse container: Karaf or Wildfly

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse

What is the recommended container for JBoss Fuse 6.1: Apache Karaf or JBoss Enterprise Application Server?

Since things like datasource configuration are much easier in an application server environment compared to that of Karaf, I am tilted towards Wildfly. But I am unsure if the choice of Wildfly is at all a recommended approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JBoss Fuse 6.2 which is being released this summer supports both EAP and Karaf. The 6.1 release and older are Karaf only.